# Struggle in configuring Java ant project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I opened the open-source java ant project called GUITAR (https://sourceforge.net/projects/guitar/) in the eclipse (my OS is Ubuntu). I got following errors:

1)Archive for require library:'modules/cr-iph/monkeytalk/monkeytalkIDE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.0.2' cannot be read or is not valid ZIP file

2)Archive for require library:'modules/gui-replayer-sel/resources/config/ant-contrib-0.6.'cannot be read or is not valid ZIP file

How can I fix these issues.

Comment: This project has so much files. What file do you get downloaded?

Comment: @PeterMmm I downloaded all the files. Also, I have problem of finding the main class in this java project.

Comment: They talk about an ant build.xml, but there isn't. Honestly, if I want to use some 3rd party lib and not getting up in 30 minutes in any standard IDE, I will look for another lib.

Comment: @PeterMmm If you search in youtube "GUITAR Test automation" you can see they are downloading all the source code from svn and simply they open it on eclipse.